# read public key and private key from USB security token

Tags: java, token, key-pair

I want ask that how can I use a usb security token epass3003 for encryption
Actually I want to know how to read the public key and/or the private key from the usb
I have no idea for how to use the usb token

Answer (score 0):

Next to the token you need drivers and some documentation.

Principally you should configure the token to be recogized as PKCS11 keystore.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html

Then you can use it as normal (pkcs11) keystore.